# Setting up Sass

Tags: css, sass, github-pages

I've built my portfolio site off of Github Pages. Now that I'm starting portfolio 2.0, I want to use Sass.

I've used Sass in the past but didn't have to set it up directly. So far I've installed Sass using `gem install sass` and have my file setup, but am not sure how to compile it properly.

File Structure:

```
styles.css
scss/
    _banner.scss
```

Styles.css content:

```
@import 'scss/_banner';
```

Am I missing the compiling step somewhere? It is even possible to use Sass on Github Pages?

Comment: Use Koala tool and easy to compile and works with Github pages as well http://koala-app.com/

Comment: You need to run the sass task to compile your scss folder into `styles.css`, you can't just import it like that.

Comment: @dommmm how do I do that?

Comment: This youtube tutorial is a good place to start: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fbVD32w1oTo&list=PL2CB1F80266E986EA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my solution I replaced `scss/_banner.scss` with `styles.scss`, opting to not create partial files for a single page application.

Then all you have to do is run `$ sass --watch css/styles.scss:css/styles.css` in the terminal and your CSS will be compiled each time you save your Sass file. This command points your computer to which file to compile and to where.

Thanks to @dommmm for directing me to the solution with the youtube video in the question comments.